# Admob PhoneGap Plugin with iPad

Tags: ipad, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins

I'm using this [Admob plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/smithimage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/AdMob) running on iOS like this:

```
window.plugins.AdMob.createBanner({"siteId":"my-site-id"});
window.plugins.AdMob.loadBanner();
// move banner to make it appear
window.plugins.AdMob.moveBanner({"positionX":0,"positionY":410});
```

For my iPhone app with `my-site-id` as my iPhone Admob site id, and it's working great. The problem is that when using this code for an iPad add with the `my-site-id` as my IPAD Admob site id, the add won't show. My guess is that it got something to do with the banner size, but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventyallu did some coding and would like to share inorder for the others to know.
In my .js file I identified the device screen size, and according to it, i'm passing the wnated add size. This is not originally supported in the plugin, so here is what I did to support this: In the plugin .js file I've added anothe parameter that is being transfered (other than the account Id), which is the add size, then in the plugin .h file I created a new variable that holds the device id, and according to it, in the .m file it select the needed add size to present.
If anyone needs I'll post the actuall code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out an updated [AdMob plugin](https://github.com/rajpara11/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/AdMobPlugin) where you can just pass in an adSize explicitly. The plugin example you're looking at looks like it is hardcoded to only work with 320x50 ads which is what you'd see on iPhones but not iPads.

Answer (score 0):

show banner in IPAD with banner size IPAD_PORTRAIT

```
admob.showBanner(admob.BannerSize.IPAD_PORTRAIT,admob.Position.TOP_APP);//show banner at the top of app
```

choose banner size according to device.

```
BannerSize: {
BANNER: {width:320,height:50},
IAB_MRECT:{width:300,height:250},
IAB_BANNER: {width:468,height:60},
IAB_LEADERBOARD: {width:728,height:90},
SMART_BANNER: {width:-1,height:-2},
IAB_WIDE_SKYSCRAPER: {width:160,height:600},
IPHONE_LANDSCAPE: {width:480,height:32},
IPAD_PORTRAIT: {width:769,height:90},
IPAD_LANDSCAPE: {width:1024,height:90}
}
```